# any one know how to implement a moran process in evolutionary game?

Tags: evolutionary-algorithm

this is a article of http://www.mathematica-journal.com/data/uploads/2011/05/Voelkl.pdf, but I still have little idea how to transfer it into the java code?

Answer (score 1):

The Moran Process of selection is not that hard. You select a particle with a probability of selection proportional to its fitness (there are several papers that talk about this but you can look up "Emergence of cooperation and evolutionary stability in finite populations" by Matin A. Nowak).

Once you have picked a particle for reproduction the total number of individuals have increased by one (N+1). You need to maintain the population at N so you pick a particle, randomly, to kill.